# problems with installing tensorflow using anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to use anaconda 4.5.12 to install tensorflow on an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS system with python 3.7.1 and pycharm 2018.3.3.

I issue the following terminal command:

```
conda install tensorflow
```

And this gives me:

```
Solving environment: /\-
```

(It keeps switching between /-). This just continues indefinitely. I waited for like 20 minutes at one point. **Why is this happening?**

Also, I am confused by the explanation on [this anaconda site](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/tensorflow-in-anaconda/), which gives the following terminal command:

```
conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow
conda activate tensorflow_env
```

What does this command do, and why would we use this rather than "conda install tensorflow"? I assume it creates a new environment but why do we need a new environment to install tensorflow? **Can't we just install tensorflow for all environments?** This seems messy, because I think it also means that I can not create an environment in PyCharm directly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I'm new, so I put this as an answer but really should be a comment. I have come across this link that might help you:

https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc

They say to use this command to install tensorflow with conda even on Ubuntu:

```
conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> This just continues indefinitely

This can be because you are behind a proxy that is blocking Anaconda's access to new packages and the installer keeps loading indefinitely.